# Erase and Install Ubuntu help please?

Tags: software-installation

Okay so I am installing Ubuntu via a virtualbox, but it tells me thatbit will remove everything, what do I do?

Comment: You've not told us what Ubuntu product, what release of that product, thus we're somewhat limited in understanding your question. Ubuntu offers various products that use different installers, for Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop for example; two different ISOs were offered that used different installers, Ubuntu 23.10 Server used another.. so we don't know which you're using. An install on a VM will **only erase whatever exists on that virtual machine**, so it won't impact your HOST OS (*which maybe your fear!*)

Comment: You don't need to worry and you can just click "Next" at that point. You should feel comfortable when experimenting with whatever you want inside VirtualBox, the worst thing that can happen is that you need to delete the ***virtual*** disk and recreate the VM

Comment: You are allocating virtual space, so clearing will not affect existing systems.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu installer offers various option when you are guided through the installation process. If the installer encounters an empty disc - which is typically the case when you do a fresh install into a virtual machine - the first option offered is to erase the whole disc and install Ubuntu. Which is fine, as you are using a virtual disc designated for the virtual machine only. The virtual disc is a file only on the physical disc.

When performing a install on a physical computer, you have to be of course more careful not to delete the whole disc incidentally, especially not if there is already another operating system installed on this disc.